# my strlen works differently in 2 different compilers, any explanation?

Tags: c, malloc, strlen

I'm using the gcc compiler I installed which I run from my cmd (write in the editor visual code) & for debugging I also installed visual studio.
It's my second semester and I just learned about `malloc`/`calloc` etc.

so the line:

```
ch_pointer = (char *)malloc(length * sizeof(char));
```

in my gcc compiler gives in return when I use `strlen(ch_pointer)`, `2` or `4` as an answer.

If I use a number too big (example 100) for length it also just says `strlen(ch_pointer) == 0`.

It works perfectly fine if I write it in visual studio as:

```
ch_pointer = (char *)malloc(((length + 1) * sizeof(char)) / 2 - 1);
```

and that's the only case it worked perfectly.

`get_number()` function is fine it's just making sure you will type an int type.

```
void main() {
    char *ch_pointer = '\0';
    int length = 0;
    printf("Please write down your sentence length in characters (including spaces): ");
    length = get_number();

    ch_pointer = (char *)malloc(((length + 1) * sizeof(char)) / 2 - 1); 
    ch_pointer[strlen(ch_pointer) - 1] = '\0';

    printf("Please write down your sentence: ");
    for (int filling = 0; filling < strlen(ch_pointer); filling++)
        scanf(" %c", &ch_pointer[filling]);
    for (int printing = 0; printing < strlen(ch_pointer); printing++)
        printf("%c", ch_pointer[printing]);

    free(ch_pointer);
}
```

For both compilers to work the same if I write down `4` or even `100` to get an array length `5` or `101` that ends in `'\0'` & let me type and print perfectly:

```
length = 4
strlen(ch_pointer) == 4
```

or

```
length = 100
strlen(ch_pointer) == 100
```

Comment: Why are you allocating `((length + 1) * sizeof(char)) / 2 - 1` bytes of memory? It should be `ch_pointer = malloc(length + 1);`

Answer (score 2):

There's a fundamental misunderstanding here: `strlen` doesn't know a thing about the allocated size of the array you pass in; it just walks it until it finds a null character, and returns how many characters it had to skip.

As `malloc` returns a pointer to uninitialized memory, its content is unpredictable, so calling `strlen` over it is undefined behavior - in the worst case where the memory block has no zero in it, it will even go on reading outside it, hopefully crashing the program.

Comment: `ch_pointer[strlen(ch_pointer) - 1] = '\0';` is not a no operation, `ch_pointer[strlen(ch_pointer)] = '\0';` is

Comment: @chqrlie oh yes, not having finished my coffee means higher probability of off by ones.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, `malloc()` returns a pointer to the allocated memory, the content of which is indeterminate.

Quoting `C11`, chapter 7.22.3.4

> *The `malloc` function allocates space for an object whose size is specified by `size` and
>   whose value is indeterminate.*

That said, for the `strlen()` from chapter 7.24.6.3,

> *The `strlen` function computes the length of the string pointed to by `s`.*

and

> *The `strlen` function returns the number of characters that precede the terminating null
>   character.*

So, `strlen()` experts the argument to be a *string*.

Now, by definition, the memory pointed to by the pointer returned by `malloc()` does not guarantee a null terminator to be present anywhere in the memory. Thus, you cannot run `strlen()` on that. You'll most likely invoke [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by memory overrrun.

Comment: I feel stupid, thank you very much for clarifying this, will use: while( ch_pointer[something] != '\0') or use the length the user writes, thanks very much

Comment: @barakadax: `while( ch_pointer[something] != '\0')` will be just as undefined behavior. You must write values to the bytes pointed to by `ch_pointer`. Conversely, allocating the memory with `calloc()` returns a block with all bytes initialized to `0`, hence `strlen(ch_pointer)` would return `0`.